# How to save form data before sending to URL

Tags: php, forms, post

I try to save data from a FORM to file. But when 'submit' to external URL my script doesn't see `$_POST array`. How to save `$_POST` which I send not receive.

I can save `$_POST` data I received (I sent to my script and save as post_array.txt). But I have to send it to external url.
I tried to receive and resend saved `$_POST` using `cURL` but I cannot do redirect with `$_POST`.
So my customer stays on my page but should be redirected to payment page with `$_POST` data.

```
html : <form method="POST" action="cert.php">
php :  cert.php

file_put_contents('post_array.txt', $_POST, FILE_APPEND);
$url = 'https://sandbox.przelewy24.pl/trnDirect';
$fields =['p24_merchant_id' => $_POST['p24_merchant_id'],
        'p24_session_id' => $_POST['p24_session_id'],
        'p24_amount' => $_POST['p24_amount'],
        'p24_currency' => $_POST['p24_currency'],
        'p24_sign' => md5($_POST['p24_session_id'].'|'.$_POST['p24_merchant_id'].'|'.$_POST['p24_amount'].'|'.$_POST['p24_currency'].'|'.$_POST['p24__sign'])];

//open connection
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
// this cURL dosnt have a redirect option coz it doesnt work for me :(

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents('response.txt', $response, FILE_APPEND);
// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);
```

Because cURL doesnt work as expected i want to direct send $_POST do external page. (it works well , but i dont have saved $_POST in my file)
How to save $_POST without sending data to my server/script ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase it.

Comment: Where do you send anything to that other server? What's the use of that `$fields` array?

Comment: Turn on error reporting - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/296555. See anything?

Comment: Notice double-underscore `p24__sign`. Is this throwing a warning/exception which you're not seeing because error reporting is off?

Comment: @NicoHaase , good eye :) I was sending $fields before I decided to send $_POST , i should delete "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);" and write "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_fields);"

Comment: @waterloomatt , thx i will fix that underscore

Comment: Turn on error reporting! It will find these error for you.

Comment: i dont have access to php.ini :(

Comment: You don't need to edit any other file for that, `ini_set` or `error_reporting` works fine

Comment: i put to my script these lines : ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); and it doent display any errors on screen

Comment: Perfect - you're good to go. Is your problem fixed now? If you're still having issues, edit your question with the steps you've done and the issue you're facing.

Comment: ok , i dont need to get response , i want user to follow that redirecting with $_POST / sending POST makes sending back TOKEN and autoredirect to payment method with POST and TOKEN (it happens auto via https://sandbox.przelewy24.pl/trnDirect url) / later przelewy24.pl will send me important data to url_status i gave them (when user succesfuly paid) , so how can i redirect with that curl ?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow, but sounds like you want cURL to follow redirects and pass along the request body. I can't vouch for this tutorial but the comments seem promising - https://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/

Comment: i think my php ver is too low , none of methods found works :( / thx guys for your help , i will check again after php upgrade (5.2 right now)

Answer (score 0):

- You can make a redirect with http status 307 developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307 In this case also body will be redirected.
- Another option is to do it with js, first make a request to you server, receive successful answer and then make second request using js to external URL with POST method. Maybe you will need some hidden form to do it in browser.

Comment: Can you explain all that further? That code seems to add some payment option - why should one expose that API to the end user instead of running a cURL request?

Comment: i want to use przelewy24.pl as a payment method for my customers. 1. i must send specific data by POST to external url , they redirect customer to payment page and later redirect to success.php if OK. 2. for test purpose i want to save $_POST data i send/receive